# How to iterate over all possible executions of a program?

Tags: c++, multithreading, memory-model

How to iterate over all possible executions of a program?

The C++ standard says that the behavior of a program is undefined if at least one of all possible executions of this program has a data race.

How does one get (or iterate over) all possible executions of a program for a given input?
Is there an algorithm to do this?

Right now this task seems very complicated to me.
The main problem is that a read in one thread might return a future write to this variable from another thread.
But at the time we evaluate the read, we don't know what writes will happen in another threads in the future.
More than that, what future writes will happen in other threads may depend on the value returned by this read.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255115/discussion-on-question-by-user22425122-how-to-iterate-over-all-possible-executio); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 1):

There are no tools or algorithms you can use to iterate over all possible executions of a generic C++ program.

Comment: `while (true) sleep()` does so.  Unfortunately it wastes all its time simulating uninteresting executions, and never gets to the first interesting execution.

Comment: When I made this answer I was 100% certain I was missing a trivial case. I just wanted someone smarter than me to get mad at my obviously-incorrect answer and write out a correct answer.

Comment: are there tools or algorithms non-generic C++ programs (i.e. C++ with some restrictions) then? If the restrictions aren't too limiting, then I might be fine with them.

Answer (score 1):

As many others have stated in the comments this is not a trivial problem and depending on what you actually want this can turn very complex.

**Static program analysis (with [pi-calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%CE%A0-calculus))**
So I am not very familiar with this area but I have tried my best to summarize what I think I understand. Please if there are things to improve suggest an edit. If we have a simple program with a data race such as:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

int sharedVariable = 0;

void threadFunction1() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; ++i) {
        sharedVariable += 1;
    }
}

void threadFunction2() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; ++i) {
        sharedVariable -= 1;
    }
}

int main() {
    std::thread t1(threadFunction1);
    std::thread t2(threadFunction2);

    t1.join();
    t2.join();

    std::cout << "Final sharedVariable value: " << sharedVariable << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

We will have different outputs of the sharedVariable each execution. By using pi-calculus (my poor example) we can represent the workflow of the program such as:

```
Process P = sharedVariable[sharedVariable + 1]
Process Q = sharedVariable[sharedVariable - 1]

P, Q :: = | sharedVariable[0]   // Initialize the shared variable
          | P | Q               // Run P and Q in parallel 
          | 0                   // Terminate the program
```

We can determine that there will be a data race because we are running two processes in parallel that are modifying the same value. The issue is still the complexity and perhaps the tools which can identify these races? Perhaps an idea would be to make an interpreter for reading (manually) created pi-calculus syntax?

**Dynamic race detection**
From my understanding the thing you are looking for are methods to discover if a given program contains ANY data races. There are interesting articles (although a bit old) on the topic, for example: https://dl.acm.org/doi/abs/10.1145/1147403.1147416.

The authors claim that you can use algorithm four to detect IF there is at least one data race for a memory location *x* although it might not find all of them. I quote:

> At any point during execution of the program, let Sw denote the last
> segment to write x and Sr the last segment to read x after Sw , if
> any. Let R denote a set that consists of Sr and each read-segment
> between Sw and Sr , that is parallel to Sr . We keep track of the
> segment Sw and the set R, but not the segment Sr . Initially, Sw is
> undefined and R is empty. Treat each notation of the form S′ ‖ S used
> below as an abbreviation of the clause: S′ is defined and parallel to
> S. been implicit. Now we describe an algorithm where we al- ways keep
> the last segment to write x and the last segment to read x for each
> active thread. Like Algorithm 4, this algorithm is able to detect at
> least one race if there are races. The storage requirements are
> different however; we comment on that issue in Remark 18 below. First,
> we need some definitions and results. We say that there is a current
> flow conflict in x between two segments Si and Sj , where 1 ≤ i < j ≤
> n, if at some given point, Si is the last segment to write x on its
> thread, Sj is the last segment to read x on its thread, and Si ‖ Sj .
> Current conflicts of the other three types are defined in a similar
> way. A current race in x is a current conflict of type flow, anti, or
> output. Our algorithm in this subsection is based on the following
> theorem. Theorem 17. If there is an access conflict in x of a given
> type, then there must be a current conflict in x of the same type.
> Proof. The particular type of conflict chosen is irrelevant here. For
> definiteness, assume that there is a flow conflict in x between two
> segments Si and Sj such that 1 ≤ i < j ≤ n. Focus on the moment when
> Sj becomes the last segment to read x on its thread. By hypothesis, Si
> has already written x. If it is currently the last segment to write x
> on its thread, then we have a current flow conflict, and there is
> nothing left to prove. Assume then that Si is not currently the last
> segment to write x on its thread. Let Sq denote the last segment to
> write x on the thread of Si, when Sj is the last segment to read x on
> the thread of Sj . Note that we have i < q < j. By hypothesis, Si and
> Sj are parallel. Lemma 6 then implies that either the segments Si and
> Sq are parallel, or the segments Sq and Sj are parallel. The first
> possibility is ruled out since Si and Sq belong to the same thread.
> Hence, Sq and Sj are parallel. These two segments cause a current
> conflict in x.

Comment: Thanks, this paper is interesting. There are two problems though: 1) (as I understood) the algorithm is dynamic race detection algorithm (i.e. it doesn't check all possible executions, instead it append to the program additional code which throws error when a data race happens in runtime, and then we run the program many times and pray that we get all the executions which happen in production) 2) it's not the C++ memory model discussed in the paper and I worry that there could be more executions in C++.

Comment: @user22425122 so I might be misunderstanding your question but I believe the idea behind the paper is to mathematically determine IF a race condition can occur (as the authors discuss further). This will not discover all the race conditions but I suppose it will answer the: "whether the program is data-race-free or not." question.

Comment: You can only do such things in Java like "safe" PL.

Comment: Sorry for the delay. I mean that there are 2 typical approaches to fighting data races: dynamic race detection and static program analysis. The paper describes algorithms for dynamic race detection or, in other words, for catching data races in runtime: additional checks are added to the program for every memory access (each check tests if the current memory access is in data race with memory accesses in other threads). These algorithms allow us to check if **a single execution of the program** contains data races.

Comment: Whereas I asked about the 2nd approach: "static program analysis" or "model checking". In this case we find **all possible executions of the program** and check that each of them doesn't contain data races. As a result, we know that every possible execution of our program is data-race-free, and, therefore, we don't need additional runtime checks for every memory access in the program. It seems like [CHESS](https://research.microsoft.com/projects/CHESS/) is a tool that uses similar approach (unfortunately C++ allows for more relaxed executions than "interleavings" checked by CHESS).

Comment: @user22425122 I understand! Then I think you would be more interested in looking at something like: [pi-calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%CE%A0-calculus)? Again this makes the question more computer science related but perhaps if you can figure out a workflow it would fit on stackoverflow? I have tried to update my program with an example.

Comment: Thanks, but I think I'll have to abstain from using pi-calculus because I have no idea how to convert [the math of the C++ memory model](http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~pes20/cpp/popl085ap-sewell.pdf) to pi-calculus and back.